# Why I'm unable to use the 'required' keyword in .NET 7 Preview

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

I enabled Visual Studio 2022 preview and I'm unable to use the `required` keyword which was described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required). The IDE allows me to specify the `SetsRequiredMembers` attribute tho, but not `required`. Why?

```cs
public class Account
{
    [SetsRequiredMembers]
    public Account(string username, string fullName)
    {
        (Username, FullName) = (username, fullName);
    }

    public Guid Id { get; init; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public string Username { get; init; }

    public string FullName { get; init; }

    public string Email { get; init; } = default!;

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

### csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite" Version="6.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: What does this mean? `The IDE allows me to specify the SetsRequiredMembers attribute tho, but not required.`

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, it means that: https://i.imgur.com/3IkodRA.png

Comment: Maybe they still didn't release it in the .NET 7 Preview 6?

Comment: Try adding `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>`, I'm not sure the framework version implies that.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio 2022 do you have? 17.3+?

Comment: As explained on the documentation you linked to in your post, this keyword is a C# 11 feature. If we then [look up C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11) it explains what to do to enable C# 11.

Comment: @TimothyG., Version 17.3.0 Preview 5.0

Comment: @mason, thanks. I put `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in the csproj file and it seems like it was able to compile it. However it still highlights it in a red color, but I think it is caused by ReSharper.